Mutually exclusive group with multiple argument groups
I am wondering if I could parse arguments using Python and argparse, like:
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo] (bar [baz] qux | file)

which allows following usages:
PROG aaa bbb ccc --foo    # foo=True bar='aaa' baz='bbb' qux='ccc'
PROG aaa ccc --foo        # foo=True bar='aaa' qux='ccc'
PROG /path/to/file --foo  # foo=True file='/path/to/file'

We can have solutions (1) making foo, bar, baz, qux, and file all optional, or (2) treating bar, baz, and qux collectively as an array and creating a mutually exclusive group with file and the array, however argument validation becomes complex in both ways.

Would then ccc be pigeonholed to be value of qux? That is, that bar can never take the value (at last via CLI) the value ccc? Similarly for the other argument-variable pairs?

Yes, bar never takes the value ccc. You mean you can solve if I change the signature to (bar baz [qux] | file)?

Mutually exclusive group is a simple flat 'xor' - no nested groups within it.  For fancier stuff you need to test things after parsing.

Also in a group only one argument can postional.  The rest have to be flagged.  And if you have string of postionals, only the last can be variable (?+*). Those nargs are greedy (in the re parsing sense). argparse can only do so much to figure out what your users intend.
